# Проблема с бесконечным перенаправлением в mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite

Есть такие правила в `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.ru$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/page/([^/]*)$ /?sort=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

т.е. при запросе `example.ru/пример/page/1` , насколько я понимаю, перенаправляется к   `example.ru/?sort=пример&page=1`, но при этом в адресной строке отображается `example.ru/пример/page/1`

Мне нужно добавить правило, чтобы в случае обращения к `example.ru/?page=2` перенаправляло на `example.ru/dat/page/2`, причем `url` в адресной строке менялся бы

Пробовал добавлять что-то вроде

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+)
RewriteRule .* /dat/page/%1? [R=301,L]
```

но эти два правила вместе запускают бесконечное перенаправление.
Как можно добавить их оба, чтобы бесконечных перенаправлений не возникало?

Answer (score 1):

мне помогло решение с использованием переменных окружения

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} !^$ 
RewriteRule ^ - [L] 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+)
RewriteRule .* /dat/page/%1? [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.ru$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/page/([^/]*)$ /?sort=$1&page=$2 [L,E=FINISH:1]
```

флаг `E=FINISH` устанавливает переменную окружения `FINISH` равной 1.
после перенаправления ее можно будет проверить на наличие, обращаясь к ней через `ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH` и в случае наличия такой переменной остальные правила отсекаются

[Ссылка на хабр 1](http://habrahabr.ru/post/75885/)

[Ссылка на хабр 2](http://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/)